# Heteroskedasticity-Robust Standard Errors in Median Regressions

Tags: r, regression, stata, quantile-regression, robust-standard-error

Does anyone know how to compute heteroskedasticity-robust standard errors in median regressions in R?

Assume the following example:

```
require("quantreg")

df <- iris
rq(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data = df)
```

I know that `summary.rq` offers multiple standard error options. But I do not know which option is the right one in my case. I would like to use the standard errors that Stata employs:

```
sysuse auto.dta
qreg price mpg trunk, vce(robust)
```

When running linear regressions in R, I correct standard errors with `coeftest`:

```
# Load packages
packs <- list("quantreg", "lmtest", "sandwich")
lapply(packs, require, character.only = T)
    
df <- iris
rq_outp <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data = df)
coeftest(rq_outp, vcov = vcovHC(rq_outp, type = "HC1"))
```

However, `coeftest` does apparently not work on `rq` objects.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, what does Stata's `vce(robust)` do? It definitely changes standard errors.

Comment: @BigBendRegion: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer?
[Better to have a short answer than no answer at
all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/)
Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: @Chr, my guess would have been option option `"nid"`, see also https://www.stata.com/features/overview/quantile-regression/. Have you tried if it replicates the Stata results?

Comment: I did indeed compare the standard errors in R with those in Stata using an example. R's non-adjusted standard errors were the same as the ones Stata produces with `vce(robust)`. However, they were different from standard errors that Stata generates without the `vce(robust)` option.

Answer (score 3):

There is no assumption of homoscedasticity in the quantile regression model. You need to assume independence, and you need assume linearity (or correct functional specification) of the quantile (median in your case) function, but you do not assume any particular distribution, and you do not assume homoscedasticity.

I can't say what stata might be doing here, but it does not seem right to me for this application. Whatever standard error methods are used (e.g., bootstrapping rows) should account for heteroscedasticity automatically.